# I can't execute a props parent method inside an event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

This is my React component class (`ModalExampleControlled`):

```
 class ModalExampleControlled extends React.Component {
    state = {modalOpen: false}
    handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

    handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })
    handleConfirm = () => {
        this.handleClose()
        this.props.delete(this.props.nome)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Show Modal</Button>}
                open={this.state.modalOpen}
                onClose={this.handleClose}
                basic
                size='small'
            >
                <Header icon='remove' content={'Elimina ' + this.props.nome}/>
                <Modal.Content>
                    <p>
                        {this.props.testo}
                    </p>
                </Modal.Content>
                <Modal.Actions>
                    <Button basic color='grey' inverted onClick={this.handleClose}>
                        <Icon name='remove'/> Annulla
                    </Button>
                    <Button color='red' onClick={this.handleConfirm} inverted>
                        <Icon name='checkmark' /> Conferma
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Actions>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

I can't execute `this.props.delete(this.props.nome)` inside the `handleConfirm` method (I didn't get any errors). I can do that only inside the `onClick` handler in render block:

```
<Button color='red' onClick={this.props.delete(this.props.nome)} inverted>
<Icon name='checkmark' /> Conferma
```

But I need to close the modal on `props.delete()` call.

The parent class `delete` method is this:

```
   delete = quale => e => {
        this.setState({
            openModal: '',
            loading: true,
            status: 'In cancellazione '+quale+'...'
        });
        fetch(`${helper.get_url()}/api/delete?quale=${quale}`, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
            this.setState({
                file: r.ok ? '\nEliminato: ' + quale +' ('+r.body.length+' righe)' : 'Error ' + quale,
                loading: false
            });
        })
    }
```

And the parent class render method contains the child component:

```
<ModalExampleControlled nome='prodotti' testo='Verranno eliminati i prodotti e il listino associato!'
   delete={this.delete}/>
```

I've already tried to bind my `handleConfirm` in construct without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you also made sure to bind the `this.delete` in the parent class?

Comment: use  "handleConfirm(){}" instead of "handleConfirm = ()=>{}" and try binding it also in the construcotr

Answer (score 1):

The `delete = quale => e => {}` handler returns a function.

`<Button color='red' onClick={this.props.delete(this.props.nome)} inverted>`

The above works because you are calling the function and passing in `this.props.nome` (which returns a function that accepts `e`).

You can either call the function like you did with the inline button that works or you will need to call the return function as well in your `handleConfirm()` handler.

`this.props.delete(quale)(e);`

Answer (score 0):

delete function returns a function and hence in order to execute it you need to call it like

```
handleConfirm = (e) => {
    this.handleClose()
    this.props.delete(this.props.nome)(e)
}
```

It works in case of `onClick={this.props.delete(this.props.nome)}` because onClick accepts a function and `this.props.delete(this.props.nome)` returns one